# Chromecast android send image

Tags: java, android, chromecast

i'm trying to create an application that shows on the chromecast the image selected. All images that i have in app are downloaded from web with a json parsing. I can't find a documentation about do that and i'm so confusing.. This is what i've done so far; In my class i declared:

```
private final MediaRouter.Callback mediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouter.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
        {
            CastDevice device = CastDevice.getFromBundle(route.getExtras());
            //setSelectedDevice(device);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
        {
            //setSelectedDevice(null);
        }
    };

    private MediaRouter mediaRouter;
    private MediaRouteSelector mediaRouteSelector;
```

and in onCreate() method:

```
// Chromecast
        mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(APP_ID)).build();
         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            }
```

then some methods:

```
// Chromecast
    private void startImage(String urlVideoLink) {

        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata( MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE );
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Immagine");

        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder( urlVideoLink )
                .setContentType("image/jpeg")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_NONE)
                .setMetadata( mediaMetadata )
                .build();
        Log.i("Chromecast", "Started");

    }
@Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        mediaRouter.addCallback(mediaRouteSelector, mediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        //setSelectedDevice(null);
        mediaRouter.removeCallback(mediaRouterCallback);
        super.onStop();
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mediaRouteSelector);

        return true;
    }
```

and of course the menu:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="Route"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

As you can see i've created a method called startImage() in which i pass a parameter that is the link of image as string. This method i called when i tap a button below the image onClick().. In this way it's not working.. nothing happend. I can reach the chromecast and connect to it but nothing more.. I can't understand how it works? How can i simply see the image on the chromecast?

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/browser/VideoProvider.java   get the json list that is already used and just swap in JPG where they currently do MP4's. may have to make other adjustments to the parseing of the media list. but if you just send mediaInfo objects to the reciever with PLAY , IMO it will play them.. ive switched mp4 to mp3 in this way and it just works

Comment: Ok, now i'll check it out. But what about receiver? What is it? I know that is a javascript but where exactly have i to put it? When i tried to cast a video i never used a receiver in javascript..

Comment: dont worry about the receiver yet.. just use the default which is encoded in the sample app and in your app i think

Comment: Ok, nice.. So, have you already tried the sample using the images instead mp4?

Comment: no . i changed from video to mp3 and it just worked.  get a mediaInfo instance with your JPG insteac of video and look closely at the sample apps call to LocalPlayerActivity. loadRemoteMedia(...)  that encapsulates the comm's with the receiver that you faq'd .. dont worry about that stuff . just focus on PLAY event with media -typ of JPG sitting in the MediaInfo object . of course you will have to switch "media-type" from video to something else... look it over and see if u can figure it out cause i think its polymorphic enough to just work if u switch over the media correctly ( vid-to-photo )

Comment: Ok thank you. Btw if you try let me know.